# Website Scraping using cURL and Regex

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am trying to scrap the categories using cURL and Regex. But the code that I have only extract one of the categories (**Arts, Antiques & Collectibles**).

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.lelong.com.my/Auc/List/BrowseAll.asp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<span class=CatLevel1>(.*?)<\/a>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0]. "<br>";
else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>
```

Can anyone help me correct this code to extract all the categories(without the numbers)? I've been stuck on this for a long time.
Thanks!

Sample output:
 
Arts, Antiques & Collectibles
 
B2B & Industrial Products
 
Baby
 
etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a working code with DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes

```
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.lelong.com.my/Auc/List/BrowseAll.asp");

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "CatLevel1";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
        echo $span->item(0)->nodeValue."<br>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the comment to your question suggesting a different approach and an alternative answer that probably are better suited for this job, but if you still want to do it this way you need to do a global search ([preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)) so it doesn't stop when it finds the first match and then use a loop to print the contents of the array where the results are saved. I haven't used cURL and can't test it and php isn't my strong, but the code should be something like:

```
if ( preg_match_all($regex, $page, $list) )
    $i = 0;
    while(isset($list[1][$i])) {
         echo $list[1][$i]. "<br>";
         $i++;
    }
else 
    print "Not found";
```

Sorry for any mistakes in the code.